# Couldn't connect to google.com or its subdomains

Tags: networking, macos, internet

For about 10 minutes, none of my devices connected to the Internet could connect to www.google.com, its subdomains and other Google-owned sites (e.g. youtube.com). Sites with Google Analytics installed would time out on me too.

In Terminal I typed in `ping www.google.com` and got this message:

```
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
```

..etc..

I flushed my cache using `dscacheutil -flushcache`, and I don't know if it worked or not because Google suddenly responded again but very slowly. I renewed my DHCP license through System Preferences and enabled my firewall (again, not sure if it effected it). Google worked again after 5 minutes, but I'm worried what this could have been about after reading this thread on Apple's support forum:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3660038?start=0&tstart=0

However, NONE of my devices worked (Android/Windows/Mac), so I'm really at loss here.

I am not connected to any university. This is a home connection on Mediacom.

Answer (score 0):

It seems others on social networks are reporting Google has been [down for them](https://twitter.com/#!/search/%23GoogleFail). So this might be just a temporary glitch in services that you happened to see for a sort period; especially since you say all your devices behave the same, I don't think you have anything to worry about in terms of malicious intent. To be safe, you could always check your Hosts file and have a look over your router's admin page to make sure you have adequate security in place, are using WPA2 with a good password and are using HTTPS to the router's admin page.

Comment: How do I check my Hosts file? And I _am_ connected to a wireless router with WPA-PSK/WPA2-PSK security.

Comment: If you look at the link you posted, there is a full walk through on how to find it and what to do.